# Simple 2D plot with one of the variables having 3 dimensions from previous calculation

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following data I would like to plot: awa versus t:

`awa(:,:,1) = 0.9272352, t=0`
`awa(:,:,2) = 0.6850705, t=2592000`
`awa(:,:,3) = 0.7650133, t=5184000`
`awa(:,:,4) = 0.7339441, t=7776000`
`awa(:,:,5) = 0.6162899, t=10368000` 
 etc

awa were calculated previously, but have 3 dimensions.  I have 101 of them, but want them in 1D to make a straight plot against t.  How can I do this in a function, and plotting, without renaming every single awa like this: awa1=awa(:,:,1)
awa2=awa(:,:,2) etc?

Thanks

Comment: How do you have a 3D array if `awa(:, :, 1)` returns a scalar?

Comment: @excaza Sounds like a vector in the 3rd dimension... In this case: `plot(awa, t_vec)`.

Comment: Yes, the third dimension being time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `squeeze` to remove other dimensions since their size is 1.

```
     awaSqueezed = sqeeze(awa);    % get the vector from your 3D
     plot(t,awaSqueezed)
```